# jenkins git ssl on AIX

Tags: git, jenkins, openssl

As a jenkins user from aix command line I manage to run:

```
 "git pull --rebase origin"
```

But when I try to do this from jenkins I get:

```
OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000105f, you have 1000013f
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Commands like "git reset" and "git checkout" work fine from both environment.

Only thing that I manage to find is that when I run ssh -V from aix shell:

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

But from jenkins:

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0s 11 Jun 2015
```

AIX have openssh and openssl installed from filesets:

```
$ lslpp -l | grep open | grep base
  openssh.base.client     6.0.0.6103  COMMITTED  Open Secure Shell Commands
  openssh.base.server     6.0.0.6103  COMMITTED  Open Secure Shell Server
  openssl.base             1.0.1.510  COMMITTED  Open Secure Socket Layer
  openssh.base.client     6.0.0.6103  COMMITTED  Open Secure Shell Commands
  openssh.base.server     6.0.0.6103  COMMITTED  Open Secure Shell Server
  openssl.base             1.0.1.510  COMMITTED  Open Secure Socket Layer
```

And for git client I had to install openssl from rpm:

```
$ rpm -qa | egrep "git|ssl"
openssl-1.0.1p-1
git-2.1.3-1
```

Regards

Comment: I figured it out. With "truss -e -o /tmp/truss_ssh_cli.txt ssh -V" I found out that when run from jenkins, jenkins ( or someone ) set LIBPATH to /opt/freeware/lib, and then ssh get openssl from there. I set LIBPATH="" and command went ok

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. With "truss -e -o /tmp/truss_ssh_cli.txt ssh -V" I found out that when run from jenkins, jenkins ( or someone ) set LIBPATH to /opt/freeware/lib, and then ssh get openssl from there. I set LIBPATH="" and command went ok