# I have a problem with git under Jenkins on AIX

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins, aix

I have the exact same problem as shown in this question:  [jenkins git ssl on AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350012/jenkins-git-ssl-on-aix/55867568#55867568)

However, the solution that person found does not fix the issue in my case.

I have exactly the same problem and error message from the other question, but if I remove /opt/freeware/lib from the libpath (which was the other person's solution) when I start Jenkins, I get:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command git ls-remote -h
>   ssh://git@stash.saas-p.com:7999/optio/core.git HEAD returned status
>   code 255: stdout: stderr:
>
> exec():
>   0509-036 Cannot load program git because of the following errors: 
>   0509-150 Dependent module /usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) could not be loaded.
>       0509-152 Member libiconv.so.2 is not found in archive

So, damned if I do, damned if I don't.

Comment: The correct answer for the other question would have been: you have different (and also unmatching) versions of OpenSSL and OpenSSH installed in different locations -- choose a matching pair to keep, and delete the others. Obviously this requires a competent admin.

Comment: Do you have file: `libiconv.so.2`. If not you/admin need to install it

Comment: Being AIX, it isn't `libiconv.so.2`, it is `libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)` That means a shared object inside an `ar`-archive. (See also this: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0009 ) It would be possible to merge the different libiconv.a archives, but I don't suggest that to AIX-novices.